# Vim + Mac, Is it possible to create a mapping that toggles between full screen app windows?

Tags: macos, unix, vim

I'm trying to create a mapping in my Vimrc file that [toggles full screen app windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqAr3.png)

Using Vim on a Macbook, I constantly save and then toggle to the browser app window to view my changes. I want to map this behaviour.

I tried setting:

```
nmap <leader>sl :w<cr> <C-Left>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Use *Application Switcher* available via `Command + Tab` key sequence. This way you can go back and forth using the same key sequence.

Comment: Is this mappable in Vimrc?

Comment: No, BUT `Command + Tab` is more finger friendly than `Ctrl + Arrow keys`! Of course for your desired mapping you can use `nnoremap <leader>sl :update<Bar>silent !open %<CR>` to save and open current file in your default program for that specific filetype or `nnoremap <leader>sl :update<Bar>silent !open -a /Applications/Firefox.app %<CR>` to save and open the current file in *Firefox* for example.

Comment: You should ask for or buy a second monitor.